# Alternate to mvn spring-boot:run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey

I have a spring boot application which I run using:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

and this works perfectly fine. 
I want to run this application using `java -jar` option and when I run it:

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=8080 $JAR_OPTS
```

I get this error:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.ResourceFinderException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/cat/IdeaProjects/backend/target/backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes (No such file or directory
```

I cant figure out why? And I have googled a lot without any luck.
Do we have an alternate to `mvn spring-boot:run`.

I want to do this because I am deploying on heroku and when I put in `Procfile` `web: mvn spring-boot:run`, I get errors such that mvn does not exist

EDIT
This is the code I am trying to run:

https://github.com/jasenkoh/spring-boot-jersey-hibernate

ENTIRE STACKTRACE:

```
type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet servletContainer threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet servletContainer threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.ResourceFinderException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/asfandyar/IdeaProjects/spring-boot-jersey-hibernate/target/spring-boot-jersey-hibernate-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes (No such file or directory)

    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:1011)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:961)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1053)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1045)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.createApplication(ApplicationHandler.java:385)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:342)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.ResourceFinderException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/asfandyar/IdeaProjects/spring-boot-jersey-hibernate/target/spring-boot-jersey-hibernate-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes (No such file or directory)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.create(JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.java:89)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.create(JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.java:65)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.addResourceFinder(PackageNamesScanner.java:282)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.init(PackageNamesScanner.java:198)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.<init>(PackageNamesScanner.java:154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.<init>(PackageNamesScanner.java:110)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.packages(ResourceConfig.java:680)
    com.jersey.config.JerseyInitialization.<init>(JerseyInitialization.java:15)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1350)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:1009)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:961)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1053)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1045)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.createApplication(ApplicationHandler.java:385)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:342)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/asfandyar/IdeaProjects/spring-boot-jersey-hibernate/target/spring-boot-jersey-hibernate-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes (No such file or directory)
    java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.getInputStream(JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.java:177)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.create(JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.java:87)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.create(JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.java:65)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.addResourceFinder(PackageNamesScanner.java:282)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.init(PackageNamesScanner.java:198)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.<init>(PackageNamesScanner.java:154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.<init>(PackageNamesScanner.java:110)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.packages(ResourceConfig.java:680)
    com.jersey.config.JerseyInitialization.<init>(JerseyInitialization.java:15)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1350)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:1009)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:961)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1053)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1045)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.createApplication(ApplicationHandler.java:385)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:342)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My pom file is available here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-jersey-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.jersey.Application</start-class>
        <postgresql-version>9.4.1209.jre7</postgresql-version>
        <jersey-version>2.23.1</jersey-version>
        <jackson-version>2.8.1</jackson-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End Spring -->

        <!-- Postgres -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End Postgres -->

        <!-- Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End Jersey -->

        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End Jackson -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: what is the version specified in the pom. And check the name of the jar generated in /target folder

Comment: using the <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace from the error please?

Comment: @BrianEcker Added the stacktrace

Comment: How are you creating the jar? Please add your `pom.xml` to the question.

Comment: M.Deinum pom added

Answer (score 2):

You can make your jar executable by configuring the spring boot maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Package your jar with

```
mvn package
```

You can then run your application by typing `./backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work? In what way does it not work?

Comment: I get the same error as mentioned above. Adding the goals changes nothing

Answer (score 2):

To execute a jar as you try to do :

> java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   --server.port=8080 $JAR_OPTS

You have to package your jar with the `repackage` goal of the spring boot maven plugin.
The `repackage` goal is bound to the `package` phase of the Maven lifecycle.

So this plugin configuration repackage a jar or war that is built during the package `phase` of the Maven lifecycle :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

If you execute the mvn package goal (or a goal after it), it will create two JARs in the target folder of the Maven project :

- the original JAR with a `.original` suffix (without the Spring boot classes and libraries to allow the jar to be self sufficient to be started)
- the runnable JAR that will have the classic JAR name.

If you don't want to add this configuration, you can execute the repackage command directly from the Maven command :

```
 mvn package spring-boot:repackage
```

Reference :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin

Comment: This unfortunately does not work. Please check the Edits above. Thanks for assistance